# Using VBA to Move Certain Data to the Right

Tags: excel, list, vba, move

In a list, I want to move the non "P" items over to the right on the same sheet.  Then I need to copy the "P" items down to match the number of items on the right.  Please see example for clarification.

[Right Click on Link and Save File for Sample](http://goobee.info/stuff/example.xlsx)

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub HTH()
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim rCell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each rCell In Worksheets("Raw Data").UsedRange.Resize(, 1)
        With rCell
            If UCase(Left(.Value, 1)) = "P" Then
                vArray = .Resize(, 11).Value
            ElseIf IsNumeric(.Value) And Not IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                .Offset(-1, 12).Resize(, 11).Value = .Resize(, 11).Value
                If IsNumeric(.Offset(1).Value) And Not IsEmpty(.Offset(1).Value) Then
                    .Resize(, 11).Value = vArray
                Else
                    .Resize(, 11).Value = ""
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next      

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I presumed you could just manually copy the header but if you need it automated then add this:

```
With Worksheets("Raw Data")
    .Cells(1, "M").Resize(, 11).Value = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 11).Value
End With
```

If you need the yellow highlight down the middle then add this:

```
 With Columns("L:L").Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .Color = 65535
 End With
```

Comment: It doesn't copy some of the birthdays over to the right.  I'll pick through the VBA and see if I can fix or learn from it.  Thanks.

Comment: I see what you mean, I hadnt noticed that.  It will be an easy change but I cannot follow the pattern. In your example, for the first name 'Mary' her birthday just seems to dissapear??

Comment: Oops, I spoke too soon. Some of the DOBs moved to the right are on the wrong row. See Cells S1, S4, S8, S28 and S31. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on the sample, the "P" DOBs should not be copied over.  See Cells S1, S4, S8, S28 and S31. Thanks

Comment: Can you upload a better sample, its a bit unclear or I'm confused as to exactly what you want now.  I'm sure we can get it sorted for you tho.

Comment: Here you go, you are very close.  My original sample was wrong, "P" DOBs go on the left side, "non-P" DOBs go on the left.  Please see attached screenshot.  http://goobee.info/stuff/screenshot2.jpg

Comment: Sorry but your last comment still does not make sense _"P" DOBs go on the left side, "non-P" DOBs go on the left._  Anyway, I have edited the code again.  It produces the results you have shown in both your screenshot and your example file.  If this is not what you want then please clearly explain with a sample file exactly what you need.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The "P" row items are on the left side, the non "P" row items are on the right (of the yellow fill).  It appears to work now.  Thanks.  FYI, the yellow fill was just for illustration purposes.

Comment: Okay, then you should mark the appropriate solution as solved.

Comment: Dan, you mark questions as solved by clicking the accept answer tick underneath the up/down vote arrows.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MoveP()
' Move non P rows to right,
' starting with the row of the P above it,
' and add P info on each row

' If you want to backup before starting uncomment next two rows of code
'    Sheets("Raw Data").Select
'    Sheets("Raw Data").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)

Dim maxRows as Integer
Dim emptyRowsToStopAt
Dim emptyRows
Dim cell1Text As String
Dim currentRightRow As Integer
Dim currentPRow As Integer

maxRows = 150 ' change this if you want to process more (or less)
emptyRowsToStopAt = 5
currentRightRow = 0
currentPRow = 0

For i = 2 To maxRows

    If emptyRows > emptyRowsToStopAt Then 
       Exit For
    End If

    cell1Text = Cells(i, 1)
    Dim startsWithP As Boolean
    startsWithP = InStr(1, cell1Text, "P")

    If startsWithP Then
        currentPRow = i
        currentRightRow = currentPRow ' we start with the same line

        emptyRows = 0

    ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Or Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
    '    ' its an empty cell
        emptyRows = emptyRows + 1

    Else ' its a non P entry
        emptyRows = 0
        'copy info from left to correct line on right
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Range(Cells(currentRightRow, 13), Cells(currentRightRow, 13)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        ' duplicate PRow to left (when non-p was not copied to PRow)
        ' -- see note below: only 3 cells duplicated
        If currentPRow <> currentRightRow Then ' not on the original P Row
            ' copy p heading
            Range(Cells(currentPRow, 1), Cells(currentPRow, 3)).Select 
            ' only first 3 cells copied
            ' change '3' to '11' if you want all
            Selection.Copy

            ' past p heading on current row
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If ' non p row copied to originally non p row

        ' and mark current row as written
        currentRightRow = currentRightRow + 1
    End If
Next

Call CleanupPtable

End Sub

Sub CleanupPtable()
'
' Clean up the P table Macro
' Adapted from macro recorded 08/06/2012 by pashute
'
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 11)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ' yellow column
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 36

    ' yellow column lines
    Columns("L:L").Select
    ' Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    ' Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    '   With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    '    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    '    .Weight = xlThin
    '    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    ' End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
       .LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .Weight = xlThin
       .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    ' yellow column width
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 2.43

    ' Automatic filters to all fields
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter

    ' autofit
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Two of the P items are not line up correctly but everything else works well.  I'll play with it and see if I can fix or learn from the VBA.  Thanks.

Comment: I worked on this for an hour. So... What doesn't work?

The code is very well commented, so you should be able to understand it completely.

I can debug it. Which P lines not alligned?

Comment: How do I add a comment to reafidy's answer?

In both Chrome and IE there's no Add-Comment button only on my own answer.

Anyway his code (apart from not adding the headers and yellow)
seems more elegant but how does it work?
I only see him adding to an array. How does the array on the left right get emptied, and how is the array written to the correct positions in the Excel?

Comment: You are very close, there are spaces that is throwing it off.  See attached screenshot.  http://goobee.info/stuff/screenshot2.jpg

Comment: @pashute, posting comments on other members solutions requires 50 reputation.